# LLDB print a variable named class

Tags: c, lldb

I have a C programm in which a variable called `class` is used.

I'm trying to debug it with LLDB but I'm encountering the following problem:

```
(lldb) print class
error: warning: declaration does not declare anything
error: declaration of anonymous class must be a definition
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

I believe this problem occurs because `class` is a reserved keyword in C++ and LLDB interprets the code passed to `print` as C++. Is there still a way to print the content of my variable?

(Please do not advise me to rename the variable, I would have come up with this myself, if it was possible)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the lldb expression parser uses C++ references to implement the job of finding & extracting results from the expressions we run.  So we currently have to compile the expressions as C++ expressions, and as you guessed, you can't use "class" in a C++ expression. At some point, we have to teach clang how to do "C with references" and then we'll be able to compile & execute real C expressions.

However, provided you have debug information for "class", you can print the value of the variable using the "frame variable" command, i.e.:

```
(lldb) frame variable class
```

The "frame variable" command does not use the expression parser, it goes directly to the debug information, extracts the type & location of the variable, and prints that directly.  So it doesn't suffer this restriction.  If "class" is a global variable, not a frame local, use `target variable` instead.

`frame variable` does support a limited set of "expression-like" features, you can say:

```
(lldb) frame variable class.member
```

or

```
(lldb) frame variable *class
```

but you can't use it to call functions or pass the variable to a function call.

If you need to do that you can run the command:

```
(lldb) frame variable -L class
```

which will print the location of the variable.  Usually that's some address, in which case you can use

```
 (TypeOfClass *) <Address From Frame Variable>
```

in your expression in place of "class".  If the location turns out to be a register, then use "$" appropriately cast in your expression.  If you are going to use the variable in a number of expressions, remember you can do:

```
(lldb) expr TypeOfClass *$class = (TypeOfClass *) <Address From Frame Variable>
```

and then just use $class in your subsequent expressions.  If you got super-motivated, you could even write a Python command that automates these steps...